# saltstack: alcali_postgres.py not supporting prep_jid()

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, salt-stack

I'm trying to set up salt, alcali and postgresql in a kubernetes cluster with rancher. the alcali_postgres returner is defined to handle job_ids from master to pgsql db.

When I install the helm chart and container is ready I see the following logs:

```
    [ERROR ] Returner 'alcali_postgres' does not support function prep_jid
    [ERROR ] An un-handled exception was caught by Salt's global exception handler:
    KeyError: "Returner 'alcali_postgres' does not support function prep_jid"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "salt/utils/job.py", line 71, in store_job
    mminion.returners[jidstore_fstr](False, passed_jid=load["jid"])
    File "salt/loader/lazy.py", line 336, in __getitem__
    super().__getitem__(item) # try to get the item from the dictionary
    File "salt/utils/lazy.py", line 105, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
    KeyError: 'alcali_postgres.prep_jid'
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/envs/tmpsmjmchis/bin/salt", line 118, in <module>
    File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/envs/tmpsmjmchis/bin/salt", line 113, in redirect
    File "salt/scripts.py", line 454, in salt_run
    client.run()
    File "salt/cli/run.py", line 34, in run
    ret = runner.run()
    File "salt/runner.py", line 300, in run
    ret = self._proc_function(
    File "salt/client/mixins.py", line 538, in _proc_function
    return instance.low(fun, low)
    File "salt/client/mixins.py", line 416, in low
    salt.utils.job.store_job(
    File "salt/utils/job.py", line 75, in store_job
    raise KeyError(emsg)
    KeyError: "Returner 'alcali_postgres' does not support function prep_jid"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "salt/utils/job.py", line 71, in store_job
    File "salt/loader/lazy.py", line 336, in __getitem__
    File "salt/utils/lazy.py", line 105, in __getitem__
    KeyError: 'alcali_postgres.prep_jid'
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/envs/tmpsmjmchis/bin/salt", line 118, in <module>
    File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/envs/tmpsmjmchis/bin/salt", line 113, in redirect
    File "salt/scripts.py", line 454, in salt_run
    File "salt/cli/run.py", line 34, in run
    File "salt/runner.py", line 300, in run
    File "salt/client/mixins.py", line 538, in _proc_function
    File "salt/client/mixins.py", line 416, in low
    File "salt/utils/job.py", line 75, in store_job
    KeyError: "Returner 'alcali_postgres' does not support function prep_jid"
    [639] Failed to execute script 'salt' due to unhandled exception!
    Salt-Master ready...
    --- logging salt messages from /var/log/salt ---
    ==> /var/log/salt/api <==
    new_conn = self._from_server_socket(self.server.socket)
    File "cheroot/connections.py", line 272, in _from_server_socket
    s, ssl_env = self.server.ssl_adapter.wrap(s)
    File "cheroot/ssl/builtin.py", line 277, in wrap
    s = self.context.wrap_socket(
    File "ssl.py", line 501, in wrap_socket
    File "ssl.py", line 1041, in _create
    File "ssl.py", line 1310, in do_handshake
    ssl.SSLZeroReturnError: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1129)
```

I had a look at the alcali_postgres.py returner, the function is defined:

```
def prep_jid(nocache=False, passed_jid=None):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    """
    Do any work necessary to prepare a JID, including sending a custom id
    """
    return passed_jid if passed_jid is not None else salt.utils.jid.gen_jid(__opts__)
```

I'm using salt v3005.1 which should support prep_jid(): https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3005/ref/returners/all/salt.returners.postgres.html

I cant figure out why this error comes up. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/latenighttales/alcali/issues/501